# Passing data using delegates from xib to VC

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, iglistkit

I'm trying to pass data two levels up from the xib into a VC so I can navigate to a separate view. I do get the data in the IGListKit Section but for some reason `passDataFromSectionUp` function doesn't trigger the `print("like")` function within the VC.

VC

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, PassSectionDelegate {

func passDataFromSectionUp(sectionController: ExperiencesSectionController) {
    print("Like"); //Doesn't trigger
}
```

IGListKit Section

```
protocol PassSectionDelegate: class {
  func passDataFromSectionUp(sectionController: ExperiencesSectionController);
}

class ExperiencesSectionController: ListSectionController, UpdateDataDelegate {

weak var delegate: PassSectionDelegate? = nil;

func passUpdateData(data: String) {
    print(data) //Data gets received
    delegate?.passDataFromSectionUp(sectionController: self);
}

...

if let cell = cell as? CarouselControlCell {
        cell.delegate = self;
    }
```

xib

```
protocol UpdateDataDelegate: class {
  func passUpdateData(data: String);
}

class CarouselControlCell: UICollectionViewCell {

weak var delegate: UpdateDataDelegate? = nil

@IBAction func addUpdate(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.passUpdateData(data: "teeest");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `delegate: PassSectionDelegate` variable in your `ExperiencesSectionController` class is set to nil, and was never updated given the code you shared. When calling `delegate?.passDataFromSectionUp(sectionController: self)`, the `delegate` variable will thus be identified as `nil` and, subsequently, nothing will be executed.

Comment: But even if I initialize it like this `weak var delegate: PassSectionDelegate?;` nothing changes. I tried it before but it made no difference.

Comment: ... and also one more question around that - in the `CarouselControlCell` the delegate variable is also `= nil` but it passes on the data to the `ExperiencesSectionController`. Why does that work but a level higher does not?  Thanks, man!

Comment: No worries mate! The thing is, although you have `weak var delegate: PassSectionDelegate? = nil` in your `ExperiencesSectionController`, you did reassign it using the following code block `if let cell = cell as? CarouselControlCell { cell.delegate = self }`. At the higher level, however, your delegate was initialized to `nil` and was never mutated.

Comment: I see what you mean. I have to initialize it in the previous level. I did it here and it worked like a charm - `func listAdapter(_ listAdapter: ListAdapter, sectionControllerFor object: Any) -> ListSectionController {
        let sectionController = ExperiencesSectionController()
        sectionController.delegate = self
        return sectionController;
    }` This is in the VC.